# How to detect refresh of a webpage in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In chrome extension - chrome.tabs does not have any direct event to be fired when a page is refreshed on a particular tab.
We do have an onUpdated event which passes all the changes as arguments in its callback that has taken place since the last update when fired.

`Is there any way of detecting through changes in the onUpdated event or in any other event to precisely detect the event of the page getting refreshed in a particular tab`